# Are there any system-defined/built-in styles or CSS features that simulate the look of menu selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to simulate the look of a menu and have it follow the current colors/styles the system uses for highlighting.

For instance, given this div...

```
<div>Make Me Look Like I'm a Menu Item that's Hovered Over</div>
```

...are there any ***system-defined*** styles/classes/selectors/whatevers that I can apply to the CSS for that div to make it look like it's a highlighted menu item?

> *Note: By 'System-Defined' I mean that of the OS. For instance, Windows has a default of blue for the highlight, but you can apply a 'Forest' theme which redefines it as green across all applications.  I wanted my web page to follow that since this particular feature is emulating a menu*

If it matters, this is for Google Chrome only.

> Note: I know I can define my own 'highlighted' class in CSS where I set the font and the text and background colors as that's what I'm currently doing, but that means ***I*** am defining those things, not picking up those used by the system, which is what I'm trying to do.

I'm not even sure the system defines such things.  That is basically what I am asking... if it does.

If not, are there any constants that I can access via Javascript which I could then apply programmatically? That too would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With caveats…

Form controls generally adopt the system colors, sizes, fonts, etc. That requires no effort on your part.

A specification for pulling fonts, colors, and other attributes from the user’s operating system dates back to [1998 and CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand), was continued [in CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-shorthand), and is still [in CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop) and unchanged. Looking at *just fonts* (edit: I added menu colors as the last two), the set of options is limited but straightforward:

- `font:caption` The font used for captioned controls (e.g., buttons, drop-downs, etc.).
- `font:icon` The font used to label icons.
- `font:menu` The font used in menus (e.g., dropdown menus and menu lists).
- `font:message-box` The font used in dialog boxes.
- `font:small-caption` The font used for labeling small controls.
- `font:status-bar` The font used in window status bars.
- `color:menu` Menu background.
- `color:menutext` Text in menus.

Then there is Apple breaking from the spec, with things like `font:-apple-system-caption1`. So it is kind of a moving target.

[CSS system colors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css-system) are explicitly [deprecated in favor of `appearance`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#appearance), which appears to be missing from the spec referenced from the deprecation note.

I have more detail and links in the post from July 2015 titled "[CSS and System Fonts](http://adrianroselli.com/2015/07/css-and-system-fonts.html)."

In short, read the spec, pull some examples, and test it. There is a CodePen example in my post that you can use as a base.

Comment: Whoa!  That's an awesome wealth of info there.  Days of googling didn't share anything like that.  This is why I love SO!  Great find.

Comment: Note: no guarantee the menu colors will work. Good luck.

Comment: It's definitely a start!  And if it doesn't work, then I'll just do what I'm doing now, which is define it myself.  Not optimal, but not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you're asking if there are already implemented/coded CSS classes that you can apply to some DIV element to make it look highlighted.

What do you mean when you say "System", are you referring to CSS 3.0 itself?

Anyway, I don't think that CSS itself will provide you with predefined classes and looks, for that you need to do one of 2 things:

1. As you already mentioned, write your own CSS, or
2. Take a nice framework to do it for you

You might want to take a look at:

- Bootstrap, http://getbootstrap.com/
- HTML5 Boilerplate, https://html5boilerplate.com/
- Semantic UI, http://semantic-ui.com/

These frameworks have lots of completed design patterns you can imply, so they are system (framework) defined, and not user defined.

Related to highlighter itself, there is a nice tutorial on how to do this simply: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001391.htm

**General notice:** When you work with CSS, your "Operating System" is your Browser which renders your HTML + CSS + JavaScript code, so different browsers might preview same code with slight differences.

Hope this helps,
All best,

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of.  Oh, for the record, by 'system defined' I meant basically at the OS level.  For instance, on Windows, it's blue by default, but someone can apply a theme that makes it green.  Chrome's menus all follow that.  Since my web page is a popup that's actually simulating a context menu, I wanted it too to pick that up.  Didn't know if CSS exposed things from the system that way. Guess not.

Comment: Oh, now I fully understand your question. Seems like you were working with desktop app development. In that terms your "Operating system" is specific browser, so full answer to your question would be:

1) Yup, frameworks are what you need
2) Different browsers renders (shows) some elements on different ways, so when you develop you want to check design on several of them.

Related to highlighter itself, there is a simple tutorial how to make it: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001391.htm

Comment: Yeah, what I was wondering is about how the OS displays the interface for apps which run within it.  For instance, even if two different browsers render differently (which is bad unto itself, but I digress) the OS-portions of it are generally the same, meaning the application's main window, the main menus, the preference panes, etc.  What I was wondering is if CSS (or something accessible via Javascript) took that into account, giving you access to that information.

Comment: @Technogeek, frameworks are _not_ what OP needs. Frameworks do not inherit from the OS level. CSS has that built in, but frameworks are generally opinionated and make it hard to define OS styles without lots of overrides.